# how can i run Go project in windows 10 using mingw64

Tags: linux, windows, go, operating-system, mingw-w64

i want to use make command in windows 10 and have installed mingw64 and add it in my path variable and all things are installed like gcc , go Language but when i run a install command it gives me following error

> C:/Users/Mustafa Shah/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gohornet/grocksdb@v1.7.1-0.20220426081058-60f50d7c59e8/dist/windows_amd64/lib/librocksdb.a(trace_record_result.cc.obj):trace_record_result.cc:(.text+0xe2f): undefined reference to _Unwind_SjLj_Unregister
> C:/Users/Mustafa Shah/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gohornet/grocksdb@v1.7.1-0.20220426081058-60f50d7c59e8/dist/windows_amd64/lib/librocksdb.a(trace_record_result.cc.obj):trace_record_result.cc:(.text+0xe70): undefined reference collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:40: install] Error 2